# Issue with dynamically setting `grid-template-areas`

Tags: javascript, css, css-grid

**Background**: I'm writing an app in vanilla JS which can dynamically generate and update CSS grid properties. In particular, I'm interested in setting `grid-template-areas` dynamically. This example might get convoluted, so [here's a CodeSandbox link to the current state of the project](https://codesandbox.io/s/50j604jq44).

---

**Expected behavior**: I'm able to set these properties on initial render without any issues. The code for that looks something like this:

```
function GridMap(targetElement, { 
    aspectWidth, 
    aspectHeight, 
    density, 
    defaultTrackName = `x` 
}) {

    /* output: [`x x`, `x x`] */
    this.areaMap = Array.from(
        Array(aspectHeight)
            .map(() => `${defaultTrackName} `
                .repeat(aspectWidth)
                .trim()
            )
    )

    /* assign CSS grid properties to target element */
    this.targetElement.style.display = `grid`
    this.targetElement.style.gridTemplateAreas = this.areaMap
        .map(row => `"${row}"`) // output: [`"x x"`, `"x x"`]
        .join(` `) // output: `"x x" " x x"`
}

const target = document.getElementById(`target`)
const grid = new GridMap(target, {
    aspectWidth: 2,
    aspectHeight: 2,
    density: 1,
})
```

Which results in the following element:

```
<div id="target" style="display: grid; grid-template-areas: "x x" "x x";"></div>
```

---

**Problem**: The above code works **on initial render**. It will generate a correct element like I show above. But when I try to do it afterwards with different (dynamically generated) properties, the element does not get updated. From this point on it's hard to isolate code to give a good example, so [here's the project so far on CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/50j604jq44). This is what the code in question looks like:

```
function Entity({ trackName, shape }) {
  this.trackName = trackName
  this.shape = shape
    .split(`\n`)
    .filter(track => track)
    .map(track => track.trim())
    .filter(track => track)
}

grid.placeEntity = function placeEntity(
    { x = 0, y = 0 },
    { shape, trackName },
  ) {
    let currentEntityRow = 0

    grid.areaMap = grid.areaMap.map((row, i) => {
      if (currentEntityRow < shape.length) {
        if (i >= y) {
          row = row.split(` `)
          row.splice(
            x,
            shape[currentEntityRow].split(` `).length,
            ...shape[currentEntityRow].split(` `).map(() => trackName),
          )

          row = row.join(` `)
          currentEntityRow += 1
        }
      }

      return row
    })

    grid.update()
}

const entity = new Entity({
    trackName: `entity`,
    shape: `
        o o
        o
    `
})

grid.placeEntity({ x = 1, y = 1 }, entity)
```

Looking at the console output in my [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/50j604jq44), you see that the new `grid.areaMap` does indeed get generated. But for some reason, when trying to update it via `grid.placeEntity()`, the updates aren't reflected in the newly rendered element.

---

**What I've tried**:

- Getting rid of the entire `grid.placeEntity` call and:

  - ...directly setting `element.style.gridTemplateAreas` to something simple like `"foo bar" "hello world"`. **This works as expected**.
  - ...directly setting `element.style.gridTemplateAreas` to the exact same string I am generating in the above example. **This doesn't work!** This tells me that there's a problem with how I'm generating `grid.areaMap`, but I can't point out that problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found the problem**: Named CSS grid tracks must always be adjacent and must always form a rectangle. [Example here](https://codepen.io/radotreyes/pen/PybZEp):

```
#grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(4, 100px);
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 100px);

  /* this isn't valid CSS */
  grid-template-areas:
    'entity-1 entity-2'
    'entity-2 entity-4';

  /* this is valid */
  grid-template-areas:
     'entity-1 entity-2'
     'entity-3 entity-4';
}
```

Makes sense, but kinda sucks as far as what this project is trying to do. I'm sure there's a workaround to be found here!